# How to include raw files without Android Studio/XML?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with Sublime Text & a command line ANT build script. How do I include data files that I can access and read through code?
I tried using `getResources().openRawResource();` but the parameter is an int, not a string.
Also, I do not have the R class because it gets generated automatically. I also don't have any XML files besides AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 1):

> How to include raw files without Android Studio/XML?

The same ways that you do with Android Studio. Either:

- Add them as raw resources (e.g., to `res/raw/`) and access them via `getResources().openRawResource()`, or
- Add them as assets (to an `assets/` directory, the location of which depends on your Ant(?!?) script) and access them via `getAssets().open()`

> I tried using getResources().openRawResource(); but the parameter is an int, not a string.

Correct. That is a resource ID. For a raw resource, it will be `R.raw.something`, where `something` is the base name of the resource file. So, for a `res/raw/foo.mp3` file, you would use `R.raw.foo`. This is no different than layout resources (`R.layout`), drawable resources (`R.drawable`), and every other type of resource.

Comment: I don't have the R class or any xml files except the android manifest.

Comment: @null: "I don't have the R class" -- then there are issues with your Ant script. Since resources are very common in Android app development, you will need to fix your Ant script, or perhaps use more common tool options (e.g., Gradle).